# How to Insert multiple record to same plural IDs

Tags: sql

I have some trouble with SQL. I want to insert multiple records to the same plural IDs in the most effortless way. If you look at the picture:

[image: Table example]

For example, there are 16 Mob in "mobId" column (normally there are thousands of records). I want to enter multiple records to the same "mobId".

The new records that I want to enter in every mobId that exists:

```
itemId, min, max category, chance  """TO every "mobId" that exist"""
 100     1    2     1       100
```

When I insert a new record like that, I want to affect every "mobId" in the table. I want to enter these records in every "mobId".

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags. Please add the specific database tag only.

Comment: The row you wish to insert is a duplicate of the first row for every mobid - is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
insert into t (mobid, itemid, min, max, category, chance)
select distinct mobid, 100, 1, 2, 1, 100 from t
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using insert on select statements.
Sonething like

```
Insert into mytable(mobid,itemid,min,max,category,chance)
Select distinct mobId, 100,1,2,1,100 from mytable;
```

In this way the select should insert a record for every mobid already existing